# How to document class instatiated within class using Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use sphinx and autodoc for a large set of python modules.  How can it document a class from a module, that has been imported and insatiated in another module:

```
# module1.py
class Class1():
    def method1():
        pass


# module2.py
import module1
class Class2():
    class1 = module1.Class1()
```

I want the class1 instance in `Class2()` to show up in the docs, and refer back to the module1  document.